# ¿Cómo puedo usar una sola instancia de un objeto en distintas clases?

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño

Tengo cuatro clases

```
    public class Farm{
    private double ground;
    
     public Farm(){
     ...
     }
    }
```

,

```
public class PresenterApp {

protected Farm farm;
protected Console console;

public PresenterApp() {
    console = new Console();
    farm = new Farm("Granja", 100, 100, 200, 123);
}
```

,

```
public class PresenterCrop{
    
    private PresenterApp presenterApp;
    
    public PresenterCrop() {
        this.managerCrops();
    }`
```

y

```
public class PresenterCrop{
        
        private PresenterApp presenterApp;
        
        public PresenterCrop() {
            this.managerCrops();
        }`
```

La clase "presenterApp" va a actuar como un manager de los demás presenters. En esta también es en donde creo que se debe crear el objeto de la clase "farm". El problema es el siguiente: necesito que todos los presentadores estén mirando a este objeto porque, de alguno hacer un cambio en la variable "ground", todos los demás presentadores se deben enterar y actualizarse, pero no entiendo cómo hacerlo. Ya me han sugerido algunos patrones de diseño, implementar el uso de interfaces y demás. ¿Esto es siquiera posible en Java?

Comment: Sin conocer el diseño de tu aplicación es un poco dificil recomendarte la solución más apropiada. El Observer encaja si lo que necesitas es que cada cambio en la granja sean notificado todos los presentadores para que reaccionen como consideren. El Composite no veo que aplique de ninguna manera para el problema que tienes.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones, ya que puede haber varios patrones que cumplan lo que pedis.. tambien podrias tener una clase estatica que maneje eso... Por lo menos en lo que mostras, no hay una sola clase farm.. para eso, la clase farm deberia ser unica

Comment: Lo siento, en mi anterior intento expliqué más a fondo lo que pasaba pero me dijeron que era muy larga la pregunta y que era probable que nadie viera el código que se anexara (puse el link del proyecto). En resumen, la aplicación gestiona una granja. Hay varios apartados de esta (animales, cultivos) y quiero que haya un presentador para cada tipo de animal y para los cultivos. ¿Qué sucede? Que solo quiero tener una granja porque de hacerse cambios en el terreno, por ejemplo, de un lado, se tiene que ver reflejado en los otro apartados de la misma (para no poner aniamales sobre cultivos, por ej

Comment: Y pues, no sé si sea cuestión de opinión en este caso siendo que en realidad no sé cómo solucionarlo. Sugerí lo de los patrones de diseño porque vi que a alguien más se lo recomendaron
En todo caso, el proyecto se puede ver mejor en https://github.com/Dete110910/Farm-Manager.git

Answer (score 0):

Creo, que la solución a tu problema es un patrón pero yo usaría otro distinto a los comentados anteriormente. En mi caso si la granja debe ser único utilizaría un Singleton.

El patrón Singleton lo define la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) como

> En ingeniería de software, singleton o instancia única es un patrón de diseño que permite restringir la creación de objetos pertenecientes a una clase o el valor de un tipo a un único objeto.

Básicamente se trata de una clase que tiene define un elemento de esa misma clase como privado y que tienen un método de obtención de dicho objeto cuya función es la siguiente:

- Si es la primera vez que se utiliza se crea un nuevo objeto
- Si ya se ha utilizado se devuelve el objeto ya creado.

En el mismo artículo de la Wikipedia tienes este ejemplo de implementación:

```java
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;

    // Private constructor suppresses 
    private Singleton(){}

    // creador sincronizado para protegerse de posibles problemas  multi-hilo
    // otra prueba para evitar instanciación múltiple 
    private synchronized static void createInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) { 
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) createInstance();
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

La creación del objeto farm se debería hacer llamando al método estático getInstance() en lugar de llamar al constructor.

Comment: El problema está en la construcción de la granja. Si esta es dinámica (como parece ser puesto que se le pasan parámetros al constructor de la clase) el Singleton no encaja mucho a no ser que se use en conjuno con algún tipo de fábrica. Como comenté en la pregunta, dependerá mucho del diseño de su aplicación.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta simplificando un poco el problema pero a la vez siendo más específico con lo que quiero. ¿Podrías echarle un vistazo de nuevo, por favor?